# Twilio Conference statusCallbackEvent="start speaker" not functioning

Tags: twilio

My Twilio server has 3 pages
`/listener`
Sets up a `<dial>` and `<Conference statusCallback="/gather" statusCallbackEvent="speaker start">` and appends caller to said conference. In the conference, the events request should be sent on any user speaking and conference starting (starting is just used for debugging in case it's something wrong with speaking alone, but the starting request won't be sent as well).

`/gather`
Uses gather to listen to speech with `action='/parse'`

`/parse`
Parses the message.

Right now, when I set the webhook to `/gather`, I could see 2 POST requests to `/gather` and `/parse` no problem. But when I set it to `/listener`, only 1 POST request per call would appear and no subsequent requests would be sent on conference start or people speaking. Can anyone possibly tell me  any example of `statusCallbackEvent` working with gather or provide any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks to me like you are trying to use speech detection on the ongoing conference call via events?

If that is the case, then I'm afraid that is not what [`statusCallback`s in `<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallbackEvent) do. `statusCallback` events during calls are asynchronous callbacks, your response to them will not affect the ongoing call. Responding to a `statusCallback` event with TwiML will have no effect.

Subsequently, it's not possible to simultaneously continue a `<Conference>` and use [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) on the participants.

Comment: In that case, do you have any suggestion on how I might go around using speech detection during a real-time person to person call?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no feature within Twilio to do live speech detection on a person to person call.